# make 100% height image background? Site example andr*id.com

Tags: css, html, background-image

I want make 100% auto height. just like android.com. 
Here what I try:

## HTML

```
<div class="android-be-together-section mdl-typography--text-center">
      <div class="logo-font android-slogan">Hey Yah!</div>
      <div class="logo-font android-sub-slogan">SIPAK Online 2.0</div>

      <a href="#screens">
        <button class="android-fab mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          <i class="material-icons">expand_more</i>
        </button>
      </a>
    </div>
```

## CSS

```
.android-be-together-section { position:relative; background:url(../images/cover.jpg) ; background-size: cover; background-position:center; height:100%;}
```

example: [www.android.com](https://www.android.com/)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the height 100 vh instead if 100% will work. Vh stands for viewport height.

```
.android-be-together-section { position:relative; background:url(../images/cover.jpg) ; background-size: cover; background-position:center; height:100 vh;}
```

Comment: my mistake. thx by your answer sir. `height:100vh` instead `height:100%` solved my problem.